# how to change the file XML attributes in my fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I create four fragment class and set adapter in my ViewPager 
and I have one file XML standard

**test_fragment.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Egyptian Pyramids"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="171dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/description"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/image1"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/image2"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and i have four fragment class is completed code to swipe in MainActivity

**FirstFragment**

```
 public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {


    public FirstFragment () {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View inflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment, container, false);
        return inflate;

    }

}
```

how to change the attributes in `test_fragment.xml` file to show when  swiping according to each fragment

Comment: what do you mean when you say you want to 'change the attributes..'?

Comment: i want change the text and image according to each fragment Example in `FirstFragment` " welcome in first fragment " and the `SecondFragment` " welcome in Second fragment "

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting you correctly, you want to use same layout for all fragments but with the different run time values on TextView.

You have to create multiple Fragment classes and their layout files for your ease. Otherwise you can use same layout (xml) file and change their values in created res. Fragment classes (as you have stated in question).

For e.g. 
`FirstFragment -> fragment.xml
SecondFragment -> fragment.xml
ThirdFragment -> fragment.xml
FourthFragment -> fragment.xml`

in onViewCreated method of respective fragment classes change your "xml attributes".

OR the better one

`FirstFragment -> fragment_one.xml
SecondFragment -> fragment_two.xml
ThirdFragment -> fragment_three.xml
FourthFragment -> fragment_four.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by:

1) In your fragment XML (each fragment will have his own XML). To every fragment give different text and image attributes.

2) Or if you want to have one XML for all your fragment, just change programmatically your attributes:

```
TEXT_VIEW.setText("...") 
IMAGE.setImageResource(....)
```

every time you swipe to new fragment, you can catch your swipping with: `addOnPageChangeListener`